# Как убрать ответ?

Tags: поддержка, удаление-ответов

как убрать ответ? а то мне его дислайкнули на за чтo не про что, хотя он нормланый. ну может и не правильный не знаю. где тут у вас на этом форуме кнопка?

Comment: Там больше плюсов, а не минусов уже. Такие вопросы надо задавать на мете с меткой [поддержка]. Хотя наверняка это дубликат, т.е. стоило поискать похожие вопросы перед заданием

Comment: @dIm0n Да я ему минус поставил, а потом снял. А плюс кто-то другой. Дупликат лен искать... А метки потому что вопрос перенесли.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если вы не уверены в правильности ответа, то напишите не ответ, а просто комментарий.

Удалить ответ можно нажав на кнопку "удалить", она ниже вашего сообщения:

> [image: Скриншот:]